# Dropwizard : Ignore PropertyNamingStrategy in one resource class

Tags: rest, dropwizard

The following way,

environment.getObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);

we can set PropertyNamingStrategy for all resources apis in Dropwizard project. We have used this in our project.

What I wanted to do is that in case of 1 resource file, I do not wanted to use any PropertyNamingStrategy. In all other resource, I wanted to use it. Is it possible to do in Dropwizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it on resource level AFAIK but you can do it on DTO class level. I'm assuming you're using an existing DTO class for that particular resource. As a solution you can extend that class.

```
@JsonNaming(value = PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
public class MyDtoWithUnderscore extends MyDto {

   public MyDtoWithUnderscore(){}
}
```